# While loading my webpage shows such error

Tags: c#

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Restart your computer.I think it will rectifies try at once.

Comment: Yes It works while restarts my computer.Thanks.